# How do I fix "Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context"

Tags: javascript

I was making a weather thing using weather.gov API and when I used this code I got an error.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context
```

**Code:**

```
$.getJSON("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/DTX/49,12/forecast", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i == 14; i++) {
        if(data['properties']['periods'][i]['name'] == 'Tonight')
        let ex = data['properties']['periods'][i]
    }
});
```

Every time I look this up I get discord stuff.

Comment: `if` without `{...}` means the following "single-statement" is run. This is in contrast to using `{...}` making a "block". `let` can only be used in a block, not a single-statement.

Comment: You should start using curly brackets properly: `if (thing === condition) { ...code })` but it's also not clear what you're meant to be doing with `ex` since you can't return it from a callback.

Comment: "*Every time I look this up I get discord stuff.*" And why is that a problem? It's not even related to Discord. Nor to jQuery. The fix should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it declaring your variable outside the loop, also i*ts more efficient*:

```
let ex;

$.getJSON("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/DTX/49,12/forecast", function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i == 14; i++) {
            if(data['properties']['periods'][i]['name'] == 'Tonight')
            ex = data['properties']['periods'][i]
        } });
```